# jquery autocomplete with IFRAME sandbox in Google Apps Script

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I have an input field within a form, which I would like to include autocomplete to display all contacts in the users Google Contacts directory.

The ideal solution would use the Google Contacts API (however, I have not been able to achieve this).

Nevertheless, I currently have the jquery autocomplete function working with the ContactsApp class in NATIVE sandbox.

**My questions are:**

1. Why does it not work within IFRAME?  I have other code which stops working in NATIVE, so really need a solution in IFRAME.
2. If it is not possible in IFRAME, do you have experience using the Contacts API?

**Here is my code to-date:**

Google Script

```
function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar1')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
  FormApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function getAvailableTags() {
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
var list = [];
for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
  var emails = contacts[i].getEmails();
if(emails[0] != undefined){
  list.push(emails[0].getAddress());
}
}

return( list );
}
```

Html File

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<input type="text" class="width-100" id="user-input1" autocomplete="on">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTagList)
      .getAvailableTags();
});

function buildTagList(list) {
$( "#user-input1" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(list, request.term);

        response(results.slice(0, 10));
    },
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 500


  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the HtmlService restrictions [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions) courtesy of @Zig Mandel, I realised the libraries included were not from a secure page.  And therefore found the [Google hosted libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) (which are https) which solved the issue.

Google Script

```
function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar1')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
  FormApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function getAvailableTags() {
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
var list = [];
for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
  var emails = contacts[i].getEmails();
if(emails[0] != undefined){
  list.push(emails[0].getAddress());
}
}

return( list );
}
```

Html File

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> **<--- this is originally incorrect--->**

<input type="text" class="width-100" id="user-input1" autocomplete="on">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> **<-- this was also originally incorrect-->**

<script>
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTagList)
      .getAvailableTags();
});

function buildTagList(list) {
$( "#user-input1" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(list, request.term);

        response(results.slice(0, 10));
    },
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 500


  });
}
</script>
```